# What job descriptions are currently accepted as gendered?

Tags: gender-neutral

It seems to me that in my lifetime, the use of "actress" has fallen out of favor in lieu of "actor", while relatively recently the term "comedienne" has been climbing in popularity. These blog posts seem to confirm my perception: "[actress](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2006/11/is-she-an-actor-or-an-actress.html)" and "[comedienne](http://grammarist.com/usage/comedienne/)".

I wonder, in the present day, what nouns for jobs or vocations today are still gendered?

Comment: Gender-specific "actress" has probably only fallen out of favor with a few high-profile movie stars. I doubt total usage of ***actress*** relative to ***actor*** has significantly changed. The reason we see ***comedienne*** far more often in recent decades is probably just because there are far more female comics today than there once were. But as to which other gendered terms "remain" in use, I think that's largely a matter of opinion (it would be difficult to know whether there are now more of the female *referent* in any given case).

Comment: @FumbleFingers do you have a source? I know of at least one local theater company where all of their players are referred to as actors (and they have women in their company).

Comment: *In total*, not much has changed re the prevalence of [actress](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=actress&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cactress%3B%2Cc0) over the past century, but [comedienne](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comedienne&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomedienne%3B%2Cc0) has gained significant traction. Even if *all* usages "within the trade" changed, they'd represent only a tiny fraction of *total* usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You need to compare with a total [actor vs actress](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=actor%2Cactress&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=) (actor rises, so actress is _relatively_ decreasing), [comedian vs comedienne](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comedian%2Ccomedienne&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=) (little relative difference, but -enne slightly increasing). Also, I think Google's corpus of books is biased away from the situation the OP cares about.

Comment: @Mitch: I just came across [*she is professor **emerita***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+is+professor+emerita%22) last night, which struck me as *slightly* odd (Google Books "guestimates" suggest [*she is professor **emeritus***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+is+professor+emeritus%22) is over twice as common). But who could say whether the "gender-correct" (but effectively "non-standard") version reflects *pedantry*, or an ideologically-motivated plug for "feminism in academia", in any given case?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm leaning towards 'pedantry'.

Comment: @Mitch: Haha - I lean towards '[misguided] plug for the feminist perspective'. Context *may* make a difference, but it essentially it strikes me as a kind of 'inverse egalitarianism', as when people (usually somewhat facetiously) refer to God as "She" mainly because they don't like the historical baggage of the masculine form, rather than because they really think of the referent as having a gender (but it almost borders on blasphemy to refer to the Christian God as "It").

Answer (score 0):

I think waitress and hostess in the service industry still happens although the neutral "server" is the predominant descriptor from my experience in Canada now. Sometimes I hear a gendered statement on other vocations - but more often to describe a man in a role more commonly associated with women. Male nurse or male model is not uncommon for example.

But beyond that - English is pretty gender neutral on jobs descriptions these days.

Comment: "...is the predominant descriptor now" **in the United States** or Canada perhaps? It's not common in BrE, which maintains the distinction.

Comment: edited to specify locale. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Phrases such as "my brother is a male nurse"  or "my sister is a lady vicar" are  still heard; although obviously the gender of my brother or sister is  already clear,.

Comment: I suppose also the monarch (of Canada, UK etc) would be refereed to as Queen or King rather than monarch

Comment: barman and barmaid are common, though some say bar tender.

Comment: Milkman and milkmaid are different roles, he delivers milk whereas she milks cows. What ia a female milk deliverer, or a male milker called?.

Answer (score 0):

'Ballerina' comes to mind, although ballet dancer would also do.